# Win32DiskImager fails to launch

Tags: windows, disk-image

I downloaded Win32DiskImager from SourceForge, as was recommended in some Linux installation instruction (coming from Windows). The installer runs successfully and the program is installed into C:\Program Files (x86) as expected. When launching the program Windows prompts me to accept that this program can make changes, I accept and nothing happens. No service or process launches in Task Manger.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that mounted drives can cause issues with Win32DiskImager. In my case Google Drive had mounted itself on the file system. Quitting Google Drive unmounted the drive it had mounted and then Win32DiskImager launched without issue! I also had a Linux ISO mounted (I believe Windows did this automatically after download, which seems odd) and had unmounted that as well before re-launching Win32DiskImager.